# Vim saving file into a definite directory

Tags: vim

Is it possible to save the file which is being edited in vim into a definite directory?

Comment: What do you mean by definite ?

Comment: when I'm trying to save the file :w .. and pressing tab for options, it shows all the directories within C:/Users/User, but it doesn't "see" other drives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `:browse w` to open a graphical browser to allow you to change drives etc.

Answer (score 1):

you could also  use the wq /path/to/directory/ to save the file. For example if you are editing a file named example.txt, after editing you press esc then shift + q, then this is what should follow;
:wq /home/example.txt
 this also works but will live a copy of your file in in its current folder.

Comment: +1 for the `shift + q` bit